# How to output multiple files url entities on twig?

Tags: theming, files, uri

I have a file entity field that I can upload multiple files and I'm trying to render or display it inside my node twig template. The code below is what I'm trying to make it display. Tried clearing my cache but it still shows empty.

I can display the **url/uri** of a single file upload but I can't seem to figure out how I can display multiple upload files **url/uri** in the loop.

### Single file here:

```
<a href="{{ file_url(node.field_upload_file.entity.uri.value) }}">Download File</a>
```

### Multiple files Here:

```
{% for key,value in node.field_upload_file.value %}
  <a href="{{ file_url(node.field_upload_file.entity.uri.value) }}">Download File</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Is this a way to display multiple upload files url/uri in the loop? Please suggest to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to loop over the field items:

```
{% for item in node.field_upload_file %}
  <a href="{{ file_url(item.entity.uri.value) }}">Download File</a>
{% endfor %}
```